# ReactJS Parse initialisation using Back4App

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, back4app

Please, guys, I need help initializing parse from Back4App

I am using React + Vite, and Yarn package installer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVOAy.png

Comment: How are you importing the parse sdk?